# Как сделать перенос строки в PHP (echo)?

Tags: php, html

Есть такой код:

```
<?php
echo implode(',', $data["secure_category"]);
?>
```

К сожалению, в массиве очень много строк и выходят за рамки шаблона, как можно сделать, чтобы вместо запятой был  `<br>`  HTML тег? При попытке его вписать - ошибку выдаёт.

Comment: `"\n"`?...........

Comment: ошибку, которую вы нам не скажите по каким-то соображениям?

Comment: Проблема не в `<br>`, а в неправильных действиях со стороны разработчика. А `<br>` вполне себе работает...... если вывод происходит в браузер, а не консоль, например

Comment: @КириллМалышев , уже пробовал, результат: https://prnt.sc/13hpz0i , ничего не происходит.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский , "если вывод происходит в браузер, а не консоль, например " , вывод строки происходит в браузере.

Comment: @user239511 всё нормавльно выводится в браузере. Пруф: https://wtools.io/php-sandbox/b5oV  (нажать выполнить и посмотреть вкладку HTML). Так что нужен полный код, вы 100% что-то неправильно делаете......Ну и конечно текст ошибки, которая происходит, очень секретная, поэтому вы её не показываете, да?

Comment: "выходят за рамки шаблона" - что значит эта фраза?  `var_dump($data["secure_category"])` тоже в студию